# BeautifulSoup cannot find 'class' href

Tags: python, python-requests

This is the page I'm trying to scrape:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2

I want to scrape the lisbox href next to Token label.

I need to scrape href from

```
class="link-hover d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
```

so my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2').text
html = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

href = html.find(class_ = 'link-hover d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center')['href']
```

however the result is nothing.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does `print(html)` show any tags with this class? Part of the HTML may be generated by JavaScript or loaded dynamically, in which case BeautifulSoup won't help

Comment: Than.. how can I solve this problem? I know selenium would do it. But I really can't use selenium

Comment: You can try [`requests-html`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/), but it still uses Chromium under the hood. If your HTML is indeed generated by JavaScript, you'll need a way to run that JavaScript and let it interact with DOM, which is something that hasn't been implemented in plain Python yet, as far as I know. JS engines need to be fast, but plain Python is the opposite of that.

Comment: Can you give me an example using requests-html?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Comment: @barny I didn't know the font weight was part of the word.

Comment: You should really not re-post the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178084/beautifulsoup-not-getting-the-right-class).

Answer (score 1):

The element of interest is rendered by JavaScript. Thus, you will need some browser automation software to render the JavaScript, in order to get the full HTML necessary.

*Note: You could use `requests-html` which supports JavaScript rendering. However, it does use a browser automation software itself, so, in my opinion, it's best to get rid of the "middle-man".*

---

### Selenium

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2")
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("availableBalanceDropdown")
elem.click()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_content(), features="html.parser")
```

---

### Playwright

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as play:
    browser = play.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2")
    page.click("#availableBalanceDropdown")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content(), features="html.parser")
    browser.quit()
```

---

Once you have the `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object, it's just a matter of scraping for the CSS selector.

```py
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(...)    # From above examples
elems = soup.select(".link-hover.d-flex.justify-content-between.align-items-center")
```