# BeautifulSoup not getting the right class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2

I want to **scrape** the lisbox href next to Token label.

I need to **scrape** href from

```
class="link-hover d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
```

so my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2').text
html = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

href = html.find(class_ = 'link-hover d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center')['href']
```

however the result is nothing. Can anyone help me?
I really need some help.

Answer (score 1):

i think with requests library you can't do it because Cloudflare detects automation.

```py
>>> page = requests.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0xCcE984c41630878b91E20c416dA3F308855E87E2')
>>> page.status_code
403
```

The `HTTP 403` Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
instead of `bs4` try `selenium` library.
`Page title`

```py
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.title
>>> <title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
```

Comment: Is there any way to hide selenium from window to act like it's not working? The reason why I tried it with requests is that I don't want to show chrome interface working

Comment: you can use selenium [headless](https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python) mode.